# Proof: There is exactly one matrix $B\in K^{n\times m}, AB=I_m$ if $\varphi$ is surjective

Tags: matrices, group-homomorphism

Setup: K is a field, $A\in K^{m\times n}$ and $\varphi$ is a homomorphism $\varphi_A :K^n \rightarrow K^m, v\mapsto Av$.

Now I have to show, that there is exactly one matrix $B\in K^{n\times m}, AB=I_m$ if $\varphi$ is surjective.

I have no idea how to start, could you give me a hint on how to start each direction ($\Rightarrow , \Leftarrow$)?

Comment: Welcome to Maths.SX! Interpret the problem in terms of linear maps.

Comment: And how would that help me? :)

Comment: It amounts to proving that  any surjective linear map $f$ has a linear section, i. e. there exists a linear map $s: K^m\longrightarrow K^n$ such that $f\circ  s=\operatorname{id}_{K^m}$.

Comment: Could you help me a bit more? Like how to start or something? :s